# How should we announce updates to our apps, scripts, libraries, etc?

Tags: support, discussion, versioning, release

Is there a recommended best way to let the stack**apps** community know that we've released an updated version of one of our projects?

We can edit the project's page and bump the version number, but this seems to be pretty internal and hidden. Will it attract any attention such as people trying the new version to let us know of any regressions etc?

Posting a new "question" seems like definitely a bad idea, unless it's a radically new overhaul of the project like the transition of the StackAPI itself to 2.0.

But what about adding a new "answer" to your project's "question"? Do people do that?

Or adding comments... or adding new fields to the project's "question" that are not in the standard template / boilerplate?

Is there a recommended best way or a de facto way that people have been using over the years?