# I don't think this tag was [release]d properly

Tags: discussion

The [release](/questions/tagged/release) tag seems redundant.  Let's review it for burnination:

##### Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? and is it unambiguous?

No, it doesn't.  We already have tags for releases: [script](/questions/tagged/script), [app](/questions/tagged/app) and [library](/questions/tagged/library).

##### Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?

It could be used for a release, a question about something the OP is going to release or discussing something that's already been released (for example, a question about the newly released version of the Stack Exchange API).

##### Does the tag add *any* meaningful information to the post?

This tag applies to so many questions here (how many questions are about the things in the section above?) that it doesn't add any useful information.

---

Looking at each question makes a stronger case for burnination:

- [Stackviewer iOS Application](https://stackapps.com/q/7626/79306) which is tagged with [app](/questions/tagged/app), making this tag redundant.
- [How should we announce updates to our apps, scripts, libraries, etc?](https://stackapps.com/q/3718/79306), a question that is about releases, but aren't the majority of questions about released some way or another?
- [Do I need permission to use the SE API for a commercial app?](https://stackapps.com/q/2507/79306) which isn't directly related to a release.  But since this tag is applicable to almost everything here, it has it.
- [Drafting users for testing in Alpha/Beta stage?](https://stackapps.com/q/1950/79306) which is also a question about releases in general.

**Should we burninate the this tag?**

Comment: If we burninate this tag we're going to disappoint 2 watchers ...